# How to add 2 interactions on the same click (button) - navigating to the next Testimonial including switch image and switch text

Tags: javascript, function, onclick

Below the  code to declare the button click (next & previous) and connect the switch in images and testimonial_text. With this  the problem is that when you click 'previous' button, the code adds 'main' to 2 of the images and adds 'first' to 2 of the testimonial_texts. So the interface gets messed up... Help?!

```
<!-- SCRIPT DESKTOP -->
        <script>
    
        const previous_desktop = document.querySelector('.previous_desktop');
        const next_desktop = document.querySelector('.next_desktop');
        const images_desktop = document.querySelectorAll('.SecondDiv_desktop > .TestimonialDiv_desktop > .testimonials');
        const totalImages_desktop = images_desktop.length;
        const testimonials_desktop = document.querySelectorAll('.SecondDiv_desktop > .navigation-buttons > .Horizontal_swipe > .testimonials_text');
        const totalTestimonials = testimonials_desktop.length;
        let currentIndex_desktop = 0;
    
        // Event Listeners to previous and next buttons
        previous_desktop.addEventListener('click', () => {
            previousImage_desktop();
            previousText_desktop();
        })
            
    
        next_desktop.addEventListener('click', () => {
            nextImage_desktop();
            nextText_desktop();
        })
        
    
        // Function to go to next Image and Text
        function nextImage_desktop(){
    
          images_desktop[currentIndex_desktop].classList.remove('main');
            if(currentIndex_desktop == totalImages_desktop-1){
                currentIndex_desktop = 0;
            }
            else{
                currentIndex_desktop++;
            }
    
          images_desktop[currentIndex_desktop].classList.add('main');
          
        }
    
        function nextText_desktop(){
    
            testimonials_desktop[currentIndex_desktop].classList.remove('first');
            if(currentIndex_desktop == totalTestimonials-1){
                currentIndex_desktop = 0;
            }
            else{
                currentIndex_desktop++;
            }
        
            testimonials_desktop[currentIndex_desktop].classList.add('first')
    
        }
        
        // Function to go to previous Image and Text
        function previousImage_desktop(){
    
          images_desktop[currentIndex_desktop].classList.remove('main');
            if(currentIndex_desktop == 0){
                currentIndex_desktop = totalImages_desktop-1;
            }
            else{
                currentIndex_desktop--;
            }
        
          images_desktop[currentIndex_desktop].classList.add('main');
    
        }
    
        function previousText_desktop(){
    
            testimonials_desktop[currentIndex_desktop].classList.remove('first');
            if(currentIndex_desktop == 0){
                currentIndex_desktop = totalTestimonials-1;
            }
            else{
                currentIndex_desktop--;
            }
    
            testimonials_desktop[currentIndex_desktop].classList.add('first');
    
        }
        
        </script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take some time to complete the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the help topic [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Good questions normally have a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, StackOverflow has an [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) with lots of information. Thanks.

Comment: Please share your HTML code.